# How to use CakePHP exclusively for the API?

Tags: php, api, cakephp, curl, cakephp-3.0

I have a API made with CakePHP and I don't want to use the views to display something on the website, for example I'd like to be able to use api.mydomain.com/users in CURL, but if I try to go to the URL in my browser I want it to redirect to api.mydomain.com which will be my API documentation.
I want this to be for every controller.

I don't know if my question is clear, but I only want my site to serve JSON responses and nothing else. If there's a better solution to my question, I'd like to hear it too.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: While it's probably relatively easy to answer, your questions seems a little [**xy-ish**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), ie more about your considered solution, rather than about the actual technical problem. What would be the difference between these requests? Both, CURL as well as browsers are just clients as far as the server / the app is concerned. Does your API only accept JSON requests (ie requests with a proper `Accept` header, or the `.json` extension)? And what if someone issues such a request via the browser, would you really want to discard that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [JSON and XML views](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html).
In this way, you'll render a JSON response.

I don't think you should redirect to the api.mydomain.com, it's pretty common to access API through a browser, but if you really want to do it you have to take a look at `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` variable